# Scale (CSS transform) iframe based on window height

Tags: jquery, css, iframe, scale

A am trying to modify an existing working JS (https://github.com/mattnish/rad) for scaling by width to scale by height, and instead of doing a logical transform, the div continues to grow as the window size is changed, so the source continues to scale to fit, never matching the window. Width-wise scaling still works with the right logic. What should I be calling in place of the div height or am I just doing something wrong with my math?

Fiddle is https://jsfiddle.net/0jm4a7ob/17/ , but the scaling code does not work in the fiddle (even the original JS, but works as its own file)
My added code was:

```
var pHeight=this.adParent.height();
pHeight-=parseInt(this.adParent.parent().css("marginTop").replace("px",""))+parseInt(this.adParent.parent().css("marginBottom").replace("px",""));
var newScale=pHeight/this.adHeight-0.001;
var newWidth=pHeight*this.adWidth/this.adHeight;
var newHeight=this.adHeight*newWidth/this.adWidth;
```

Big thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing pHeight=this.adParent.height(); to pHeight=$(window).height(); resolved the issue. The div was apparently always a few pixels over the edge of the page and messing up the logic.